# iFrame is not rendering on button click

Tags: visualforce, iframe

```
<apex:page standardController="Lead">
 <apex:form>
  <apex:commandButton value="Send Gift">
    <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" rerender="set" status="status"/>
  </apex:commandButton> 
 </apex:form>
    <apex:iframe src="https://devapp.alyce.com/remote/v1/gift-create?rt=AYCHDDYS&ru=https://c.ap4.visual.force.com/apex/CreateGiftPage&gcfn={!$CurrentPage.parameters.gcfn}&gcln={!$CurrentPage.parameters.gcln}&gce={!$CurrentPage.parameters.gce}" id="set" width="1000" height="2000"/>

</apex:page>
```

i have used this vf as inline vf where i want the iframe to show on button click. Instead of doing this iFrame has not affecting by onclick action, it is reloading however.

Comment: Have you tried adding `iFrame` into an `outputPanel`?

Comment: yes i tried it too. no luck.

Comment: Can you please add the controller? The commandButton don't have an action.

Comment: Try doing something to put it on the page to begin with and use a show/hide visibility setting where `visible=true onClick` of the `commandButton`. Also, I suggest you wrap it in a `Div` so that it's in a different part of the DOM on your  page.